# What are the best light positions and directions to highlight the print and reduce shadow and light reflection on my OctoPi cameras?

Tags: octoprint, camera, octopi

I'm setting up multiple cameras; I have two running: one camera moving with the bed (static distance to the print) and one camera on the frame (stationary to the printer). I will add a third camera later, an endoscope nozzle camera.

However, I have several issues with this, mainly lighting, such as too much reflection on the bed and too much shadows. What is the best position and direction to add (diffused) light to my Creality Ender 3 V2 to highlight the print as much as possible without too much shadow and light reflection?

### Two examples

Too much shadow, from a Logitech C920 camera mounted to the frame of an Creality Ender 3 V2:

[image]

Too much light reflection (on the print in this case) and shadow, from a Raspberry Pi v1.3 camera mounted to the bed of another Creality Ender 3 V2:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your setup and what shadows and reflections you consider too much?

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for the suggestion. I did.

Comment: Have you considered a [ring light](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4751561) mounted to the hotend?